# How can I convert temperature data from an LM92 in Linux

Tags: c, linux, integer, signed

I am trying to read the temperature data from an LM92. Everything is fine until the temperature goes below 0, then I get bad results. I know the problem is in the conversion of the 12 bit integer with sign bit to a Linux int value, but I have have not been able to find information on doing this. I have some examples that work with Arduino and Microchip, but not with Linux GCC.

Here is an example that works with anything other than Linux:

```
// LM92 Read
int i2c_lm92Read() {
    unsigned int data;

    data = (unsigned int) i2c_read(0x4B);   
    data <<= 8;
    data |= (unsigned int) i2c_read(0x4B);
    data /= 8;

    return (int) (data * 0.0625);
}
```

The results I am getting when I hit the LM92 with freeze spray:

```
LM92: 18C
LM92: 16C
LM92: 16C
LM92: 507C
LM92: 477C
LM92: 475C
```

Comment: I found a problem in the way I was collecting the buffer data. I have it working now with this code. Still not sure how Linux sets the sign bit, so I just get it from the raw data and then multiply the result by 1 or -1.

 if (buf[0] & 0b00010000) sign = -1;
 buf[0] &= 0b1111;
 data = buf[0];
 data <<= 8;
 data |= buf[1];
 data >>= 3;
 data *= 0.0625;
 return (int)data * sign;

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
data = (unsigned int) i2c_read(0x4B);   
data <<= 8;
data |= (unsigned int) i2c_read(0x4B);
data >>= 3;

if (data >= 4096)
    data -= 8192;

return ( (double) data) * 0.0625;
```

The constant 8192 is 2^13. In the used 12/13bit representation,
-1 is equal to 8191 etc.

See http://www.kerrywong.com/2014/01/19/lm92-library-for-arduino/ for a reference
implementation.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing here, but it didn't work for me.
    
    LM92: 22C
    LM92: 22C
    LM92: 0C
    LM92: 505C
    LM92: 507C
    LM92: 493C
    LM92: 489C
LM92: 491C

Comment: Sorry, the expression need to test for 4096.

Comment: "(505 / 0.0625 - 8192) * 0.0625" is  -7 degree C which seems to be reasonable for your test.